# How to disable chef-server on boot

Tags: linux, chef

I have been trying to disable chef-server services on boot time. I looked into "/etc/init.d/" but there are no any chef related service listed. I checked service list from service --status-all but no chef related service i am able to get. I tried with "chef-server-ctl once bookshelf" command but after reboot, services are starting by itself.  I am using ubuntu 14.04 with chef 11 server. Any help would be appriciated.

```
root@talkwithmurtuza5:/home/user# chef-server-ctl status
down: bookshelf: 97s, normally up; run: log: (pid 808) 658s
down: chef-expander: 95s, normally up; run: log: (pid 806) 658s
down: chef-solr: 94s, normally up; run: log: (pid 805) 658s
down: erchef: 94s, normally up; run: log: (pid 807) 658s
down: postgresql: 93s, normally up; run: log: (pid 815) 658s
down: rabbitmq: 93s, normally up; run: log: (pid 822) 658s
```

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: I have two chef-server installed in single machine. I want to stop chef-server11 and keep running chef-12.

Comment: That is not really supported, take a backup of the 11 server and then deploy a new one for 12 of you want to be able to roll back.

Comment: I found a solution already, I made changes in chef-server config file from "/etc/init/chef-server-runsvdir.conf. I changed runlevel to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I was asking the same thing . It looks like chef uninstall will do what you want, with no data loss.

`chef-server-ctl uninstall`

https://d2avhevdwylo4t.cloudfront.net/ctl_chef_server.html#uninstall

to restore that

`chef-server-ctl reconfigure`

https://d2avhevdwylo4t.cloudfront.net/ctl_chef_server.html#reconfigure